# Problems in changing language of my iPhone app

Tags: ios, localization

Hi I've created my iPhone app for IOS 5.0 with Xcode 4.2. By default it is localized in English.
I would like to make the app appear on the app store with language "French".
From my understanding, I've to remove English language and add the French one, but this is causing some problems to me.
At first, each time I open my app in Xcode, english language is added by default, even if I have removed it previously.
Moreover, if I localize my Storyboard files in French, the file is moved to my fr folder in project, but this causes in "Copy Bundle Resources" a problem with the file that becomes red.
To make it work again, I've to remove the localization from the Storyboard files.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why would you want to remove English? Can you just add French?

Comment: I don't want English appears in the app store as one of the app languages...